# how to create a scenario where there are 6 turtles moving randomly. Once one turtle finds a spot (food) it alerts the other turtles to the spot?

Tags: netlogo

Number of turtles- 6
Moving randomly in a fixed area.
Food ( a circle spot say) occurs randomly in the area.
one random turtle if it finds it, makes the other turtles to come to the location.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer for this.  Here are some possibilities.

1. Have a gobal variable `hasFood` initialized to `nobody`; when a turtle finds food it sets it equal to `self`; every turtle checks `hasFood` each tick and moves towards the turtle (if any) it points to.
2. Give every turtle a `hasFood` attribute initialized to `nobody`; when a turtle finds food it sets this attribute on all turtles to `self`; each turtle checks this attribute and moves toward the turtle (if any) that is its value
3. Give every turtle a `hasFood` attribute initialized to `false`; when a turtle finds food it sets its attribute to `true`; each turtle with this attribute `false` checks the attribute value of other turtles and moves toward a turtle (if any) that has this attribute set to `true`

And so on.  The global variable is the cheapest approach, but it does introduce a global variable.

Comment: thank you !! will do as suggested!